# from ax2009 to ax2012, RAssetTable, Lifetime

Tags: axapta, updating, dynamics-ax-2012

all! the problem is an absent of Lifetime field in RAssetStandards table. what is should to use instead this field in cases, for example, of comparing like that: rAssetStandards.Lifetime != 0.
thanks for attention!

Comment: Please ask a question :)

Comment: Can you see the field in the user interface?

Answer (score 0):

It is a display method: you can check `if (rAssetStandards.lifetime() != 0)`